# Why is my cactus drooping?

Tags: cactus

My cactus has gone all droopy and I don't know what the problem is.

I've moved into a place with more light and I water it enough but I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Hi Liesl. Welcome to this site. Could you provide a picture of the situation?

Comment: Some cactii/succulents will "droop" in the sense that, without support they will do that. As Patrick said, a picture will help greatly!

Comment: Drooping as going soggy? If so you watered your cactus too much and you're probably too late.

Comment: "Water it enough" as applied to a cacti usually means "water too often". Roots rot, and the top'll get soggy. I generally water about once a month. Some species like a little more. A pic would be very helpful.

Comment: on the other hand, too little, and they shrivel and droop :-) Or if they're simply dead they'll droop but take time doing it so you don't know they're sick/distressed until it is too late. as for watering: Well draining soil is the secret - then they shouldn't (in theory) get over watered

Comment: If the OP would send pictures and personalize the question better I'd leave this open, otherwise I'd close this

Comment: @stormy see the question that I linked to - it should answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

If its prickly pear, I've had this problem before (generally with younger plants, or recently planted cuttings - and yes it is due to too much rain/water) I've had some success propping them up with rebar for a week or so while the ground dries up again and the cactus regains some rigidity. I can't defend the science behind this or anything, but it has worked for me in several cases.